# Pointer to a struct (or lack thereof)

Tags: pointers, struct, go

Let's say I have defined this struct:

```
type Vertex struct {
    X, Y float64
}
```

now it's perfectly legal Go to use it like this:

```
func (v *Vertex) Abs() float64 {
    return math.Sqrt(v.X*v.X + v.Y*v.Y)
}

func main() {
    v := &Vertex{3, 4}
    fmt.Println(v.Abs())
}
```

but it's also ok not to use a pointer:

```
func main() {
    v := Vertex{3, 4}
    fmt.Println(v.Abs())
}
```

The results in both cases is the same, but how are they different, internally? Does the use of pointer makes the program run faster?

PS. I get it that the `Abs()` function needs a pointer as a receiver. That explains the reason why a pointer has been used later in the main function. But why doesn't the program spit out an error when I don't use a pointer and directly call `Abs()` on a struct instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why doesn't the program spit out an error when I don't use a pointer and directly call `Abs()` on a struct instance?

Because you can get the pointer to (address of) a struct instance.

As mentioned in "[What do the terms pointer receiver and value receiver mean in Golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24391459/6309)"

> Go will auto address and auto-dereference pointers (in most cases) so `m := MyStruct{}; m.DoOtherStuff()` still works since Go automatically does `(&m).DoOtherStuff()` for you.

As illustrated by "[Don't Get Bitten by Pointer vs Non-Pointer Method Receivers in Golang](http://nathanleclaire.com/blog/2014/08/09/dont-get-bitten-by-pointer-vs-non-pointer-method-receivers-in-golang/)" or "[Go 101: Methods on Pointers vs. Values](http://zduck.com/2014/go-101-methods-on-pointers-vs-values/)", using a pointer receiver `(v *Vertex)` is great to avoid copy, since [Go passes everything by value](http://golang.org/doc/faq#pass_by_value).

The [spec mentions (Method values)](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_values):

> As with [method calls](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Calls), a reference to a non-interface method with a pointer receiver using an addressable value will automatically take the address of that value: `t.Mp` is equivalent to `(&t).Mp`.